# How do I add custom content fields to content types in Open Social?

Tags: 8

I am trying to add fields to my new custom content type in Open Social (OS), the Drupal social networking distribution. I follow the regular procedure of adding a new custom content type from `/admin/structure/types/add`.  OS will add the custom content type fine, but then after the new content type is created, the list of content types at `/admin/structure/types` shows only `Edit` or `Delete` operations in the combo box for the operations, with `Edit` being the default. Normally, there are possible operations of `Manage fields`, `Manage form display`, and `Manage display` as well in the combo box for the operations. Furthermore, when I use the normal path for adding a custom field for the content type, namely `/admin/structure/types/manage/<content type>/fields` where `<content type>` is the content type I just created, I get an error message of `The requested page could not be found`. OS exhibits the same behavior for existing content types like **Topic**. I have found this to be the case for version 8.7.8 and 8.8.10 of OS.

Does anyone know how to enable to ability to add and manage custom fields for new content types in Open Social?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer after I looked into it more. The issue is just whether the Field UI module (field_ui) is enabled or not. This is a Drupal core module and by default it is not enabled in Open Social. But once field_ui is enabled, then all of the custom fields can be managed appropriately.

Comment: Just as an FYI, to be able to display the Views in Open Social, then there is a similar procedure. That needs the views_ui module to be enabled, which is also in the list of core modules.